# SIGINT has no effect on a script

Tags: python, linux, makefile, signals, posix

I am trying to understand the behavior I have with the SIGINT signal with a script launched in two differents ways.

Here is a simple python script :

```
import time
while True:
      time.sleep(10000)
```

If I launch the script in background, check the pid and ppid (notice that it is the same as my terminal) and kill it wit SIGINT, it works :

```
user@host [~] > python script.py &
[1] 19077

user@host [~] > ps axo pid,ppid,command | grep script
19077  1055 python script.py
19093  1055 grep script

user@host [~] > kill -INT 19077
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                
  File "script.py", line 10, in <module>
    time.sleep(10000)
KeyboardInterrupt
[1]  + exit 1     python script.py
```

Now if i launch it through a Makefile :

```
user@host [~] > cat Makefile
all:
    python script.py &

user@host [~] > make
python script.py &

user@host [~] > ps axo pid,ppid,command | grep script
19118     1 python script.py
19122  1055 grep script

user@host [~] > kill -INT 19118
user@host [~] > ps axo pid,ppid,command | grep script
19118     1 python script.py
19128  1055 grep script
```

Notice that now, its ppid is 1 (init, seems logic) and it does not get killed. As if the process does not receive the signal. I changed my script to handle the signal by myself :

```
import time, signal, sys

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print 'Killed !'
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

while True:
    time.sleep(10000)
```

Now the process got killed with the handler I wrote :

```
user@host [~] > make
python script.py &
user@host [~] > ps axo pid,ppid,command | grep script
19148     1 python script.py
19152  1055 grep script
user@host [~] > kill -INT 19148
Killed !                                                                                                                                          
user@host [~] > ps axo pid,ppid,command | grep script
19158  1055 grep script
```

So my question is : why does the process does not get killed witn SIGINT when its ppid is 1 or launched with a Makefile ? I cannot understand the behavior, I know that the best way would be to kill it with SIGTERM as it is almost like a daemon but I want to understand this anyway.

In python the SIGINT signal is translated into a KeyboardInterrupt exception, I tried to caught it without any success.

I did the same script in bash and the behavior is exactly the same.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Signal handlers are inherited from the parent process and, as you demonstrate yourself, can be redefined. So either `make` redefines it. Or, for SIGINT in particular, there may be a logic that redefines the handler when the process looses its stdin or its terminal, since SIGINT is normally used for Ctrl-C. No terminal, no Ctrl-C.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I though and you said it seems that makes redefined it. I tried the following command : start-stop-daemon --start --user charly -b --exec /home/charly/script.py and the process can be killed. I only found [this](https://github.com/mturk/gnumake/blob/9c3fecf4dd76a8c802055d9bd3689d0c6c5d6167/commands.c#L542) in the gnumake source

Comment: This can maybe explain the behavior as signal handler are inherited.